# Looping through odata results with linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have an odata service from which I pull some data via linq query.

```
var results = Teams.Expand("MemberUsers").Where(t => t.Company == "MyCompany");
foreach(var result in results)
{
  ... do some stuff;
}
```

The problem I am having is that the variable result is actually of type `Team` and not of type `User`.
`MemberUsers` is a collection of `User` within `Teams`. So variable `results` only has one item but multiple users.

What is the correct syntax to access the users within `Team`?

Comment: Any time the type of what you want is different from what you have, expect that `select` will be part of the solution.

Answer (score 0):

then you need to select user:

```
var results = Teams.Expand("MemberUsers").Where(t => t.Company == "MyCompany").select(x=>x.Users).ToList();
```

Comment: I seem to get `NotSupportedException: Can only specify query options (orderby, where, take, skip) after last navigation.` for all of the suggestions here.

Answer (score 0):

```
var results = Teams.Where(t => t.Company == "MyCompany").SelectMany(t => t.MemberUsers);
```

OR

```
var results = from t in Teams
              where t.Company == "MyCompany"
              from m in t.MemberUsers
              select m;
```